# Which layer of a Clif Builder Bar is the protein vs sugar layer?

Tags: nutrition, protein

Which layer of a Clif Builder Bar is the protein vs sugar layer?

You can cleanly cut these bars in half horizontally and get two different bars. One is crunchy, and the other is chewy. Which of these contains the 20g of protein and which one contains the 17g of sugar?

Comment: Welcome to the stack Jonathan, take the [tour] when you have a moment. Unfortunately, nutrition questions are off topic here, and the proprietary construction of a granola bar probably wouldn't be on topic even if nutrition questions were on topic.

Comment: Where is the right place to ask this question?

Comment: You might try the [contact form](https://clifbarandcompany.force.com/clifbarhelpcenter/s/?language=en_US) at Clif Bar.

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant - There have been a few places that have tried and rejected nutrition. It's just not a good fit for the exchange format. That being said, like everything, the layers in a Clif bar are going to be mixed. If you are looking for the straight protein, use a powder.

Comment: Got this response

Comment: Each layer contains both sugar and protein. The soft layer has slightly more protein than the crisp layer, by gram weight.